# Is it possible to create a PHP Switch which check the url for a specific string?

Tags: php, string, url, switch-statement, trim

Is it possible to create a PHP switch, which checks a URL's for a specific string? I'm using $_GET to customize the URL'S of specific pages depending on various situations. I want to trim down the Url and check it against several cases. Here is the code I have so far.

Here is the an example of the URL:

---

**www.example.com/page/resource/view.php?id=417&module=1&menuid=4&module=1&page=4**

```
<?php

// Grabs the page URL
$url = curPageURL();
var_dump($url);

$trimURL = trim($url);
var_dump($trimmed);

$trimmed = trim($text, "resource/view.php?id=417&module=1& || &module=1&page=4");
var_dump($trimmed);

// The Switch
switch ($trimmed) {
case "menuid=1":
    echo "Menu ID  1";
    break;
case "menuid=2":
    echo "Menu ID 2";
    break;
case "menuid=2":
    echo "Menu ID 3";
    break;
default:
echo "No Menu Number Detected.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't just use `$_GET["menuid"]` in the `switch` statement without the other trimming?

Comment: You really don't want to do things that way! You're hard coding a lot of stuff, whenever there is a new menu ID you've got to update your code, that's not good programming! You want to solve this in a generic way.

Comment: If that is the easiest solution. Then I have no problem using that

Comment: @Nick - that's the only solution that makes sense in this situation.

Comment: @markus-tharkun I know, but there is no way around it. It how it was done before I was here.

Comment: @markus-tharkun I don't have that kind of resources. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have less resources, hm, interesting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
switch($_GET["menuid"]) {
    case "1":
        echo "Menu ID  1";
    break;
    case "2":
        echo "Menu ID 2";
    break;
}
```